# Converting String value from UILabel to Int returns nil | Swift 2 / Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UILabel` which contains a `String` value of a number, for example;

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

label.text = "5"
```

I am then trying to convert the string value to as an unwrapped Int constant. Previously I used `toInt` but that is now gone and I tried by doing,

```
let labelText: String = label.text!
let size: Int! = Int(labelText)
```

However size is returning a `nil` value instead of the converted value, in this case it should be a `Int` of value 5. Does anybody know where I am going wrong with the new syntax ?

Comment: Where are you assigning `"5"` to `label.text`?  Do a `print("**\(labelText)**")` right before setting the value of `size`.  What do you see?  There can't be any spaces around the `5`.  You should see `**5**`.

Comment: The value is actually "5.0"

Comment: `let size: Int! = Int(Double(labelText)!)`

Comment: You want to be careful with the forced unwraps though.  They will crash if you don't get what you expect.  You might want to do something like this: `let size = Int(Double(label.Text ?? "") ?? 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you provided should work.

Maybe the `label.text` is set to be some other value that would make the conversion fail.

Here are some examples that would make `size` to be `nil`:

```
label.text = "5+"
label.text = "5.0"
```

Yes, even "5.0" would make the conversion fail.

Explicitly cast to `Double` and cast back to `Int` should work.

If you don't like to deal with the casting stuffs (or you don't know the format of the text), you may avoid it by using `NSNumberFormatter`, here's an example:

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle

if let number = formatter.numberFromString(labelText) {
    // number is an instance of NSNumber
    size = number.integerValue
}
```

Please note that creating a `NSNumberFormatter` is a expensive operation, please cache it if possible.

Comment: The string value is actually "5.0" - a Double, that might be causing the value to be nil when converting the string to Int , So might need to convert String to Double then to Int. Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

let size = Int(labelText.text) - Int

let dsize = Double(labelText.text) - double

You might have to unwrap the label if you want to use it with in a later func.